# Error copying form "The database has been place in a state"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have 2 local Access 2016 database. I would like to copy a form from one database to the other.

When I try and pasted the copied form, I get the error "The database has been placed in a state by user....that prevents it being opened or locked.

As the databases are local, I am the only person with the database open, although both database contain linked tables.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a form from one database to another, the database where the form resides need to not have any exclusive locks set. The simplest way to ensure this is to close the database, and open them up *only* to copy the form.

Things that cause exclusive locks include modifying table design, modifying forms, modifying VBA, or explicitly open up the database exclusively.

Comment: You're a faster typer than me. :)

Comment: To my surprise that worked. I saved and closed both databases. Then re-opened them, and attempted the copy before doing anything else - and it worked. Thank you. Will accept when I can.